# Change All URLs with a Specific ID Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an html code to download files like this:

```
<a class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" href="https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.5/rufus-3.5.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download (Installer)</a>
```

```
<a class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" href="https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.5/rufus-3.5p.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download (Portable)</a>
```

I want all the URLs in the `class="wp-block-button__link` tag to change like this:

```
<a class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" href="mydomain.com/get/?url=https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.5/rufus-3.5p.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download (Portable)</a>
```

```
<a class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" href="mydomain.com/get/?url=https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.5/rufus-3.5.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download (Installer)</a>
```

I am currently changing it using Javascript like this:

```
let a = document.querySelector('.wp-block-button__link');
a.href = "mydomain.com/get/?url=" + a.href
console.log(a.outerHTML)
```

The javascript code that I use now can only change one URL, I want to change all the URLs in the `class="wp-block-button__link"` tag.

**How do I make the javascript code I use change all URLs  in the tag `class="wp-block-button__link"`, not just one URL?**

Comment: use `document.querySelectorAll` and loop through it

Comment: @AswinKumar can you write the code here ?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-button__link').forEach(a => { a.href = "mydomain.com/get/?url=" + a.href });`

Comment: thank you @briosheje , this code works well.

Comment: @RenomuReza accept any of the below answers, they show the same code.

Comment: @briosheje Yes I have tried it all, it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`:

```
let allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-button__link');
allLinks.forEach(a => {
    a.href = "mydomain.com/get/?url=" + a.href;
    console.log(a.outerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop through it with `forEach()`

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-button__link');
a.forEach((i) => i.href = "mydomain.com/get/?url=" + i.href);
```

```html
<a class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" href="https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.5/rufus-3.5.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download (Installer)</a>
<a class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" href="https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.5/rufus-3.5p.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download (Portable)</a>
```